# Cannot resolve symbols 'Fragment_Name' when it is initialized

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the 6th line "new YourFragment()" I cant understand what I am suppose to fill in here I need an example please btw its says cannot resolve symbols 'YourFragment'

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment;
    if (id == R.id.nav_cough) {
        fragment = new YourFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_colds) {
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_fever) {
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_vegetables) {
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_fruits) {
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you want to fill in? Also please edit  your question to have proper formatting - yellow is for citations (not for actual question), error messages look better formatted as code snippets.

Comment: can you post your entire Activity and YourFragment class code?

Comment: I guess he was asking for usage of some sample code. As the answer below, a custom fragment will be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you have not created a class YourFragment extending Fragment.

Open a new java class and name it YourFragment.
inside YourFragment

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: need 15 reputation :(

Comment: Mark correct no need reputation, did you see that tick below down vote?